# how can I set the username and password of a https web service within client?

Tags: web-services, https, cxf, credentials

I have created client code of an https web service using soapUI and apache-cxf-2.7.2. There is a class named MYService_BasicEndpoint_Client.java which contains this method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
    URL wsdlURL = MYServiceWcf.WSDL_LOCATION;
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) { 
        File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
        try {
            if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
            } else {
                wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    MYServiceWcf ss = new MYServiceWcf(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    IMYService port = ss.getBasicEndpoint();
    port.webserviceMethod();
}
```

But when I run it the result is http response 401 (Unauthorized) because there isn't any option to set username and password of https web service. But I can run test case of this service within soapUI because there is an option to set username and password for endpoint. how can I set them within the code above which created by soapUI and apache-cxf-2.7.2?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to SOAPUI? If not then I would recommend Jersey Client API. There is a nice example here of how to build a SOAP over REST client ( http://aruld.info/soap-over-resty-client/ )

This allows you to use Apache HTTPClient to setup your request (username, password, port and scheme) and then create the Jersey WebResource which will eventually dispatch the request

Sample configuration might look something like:

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = connector.getHTTPClient(argUsername, argPassword, 
                    argScheme, argDomain);

  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
  config.getClasses().add(SoapProvider.class);
  HttpClientJerseyHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientJerseyHandler(httpClient, null, false);
  HttpClientJerseyClient jerseyClient = new HttpClientJerseyClient(clientHandler, config);
  return jerseyClient.resource(someWSDLURL);
```